# I need help in creating a network with Server, switches and hosts with python in mininet. I am using ONOS in this

Tags: python, mininet

I need help in creating a network with Server, switches and hosts with python in mininet. I am using ONOS in this.

I'm unable to ping between the Server and the hosts. Please help me on what to add to establish connectivity between server and the host.

[Network overview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/djyyA.png)

[Commands used to establish a connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZWgya.png)
(The name of the python file in my system is Task3)

```
from mininet.topo import Topo
from mininet.net import Mininet
from mininet.node import Node
from mininet.log import setLogLevel, info
from mininet.cli import CLI
from mininet.node import OVSSwitch
from mininet.link import TCLink
 
class MyTopo( Topo ):  
    "Simple topology example."
    def __init__( self ):
        "Create custom topo."

        # Initialize topology
        Topo.__init__( self )

        # Add hosts and switches TODO
        Host1 = self.addHost('h1', ip='147.197.129.1/24', mac='00:00:00:00:00:01')
        Host2 = self.addHost('h2', ip='147.197.129.2/24', mac='00:00:00:00:00:02')
    Host3 = self.addHost('h3', ip='147.197.129.3/24', mac='00:00:00:00:00:03')
    Host4 = self.addHost('h4', ip='147.197.129.4/24', mac='00:00:00:00:00:04')
    Host5 = self.addHost('h5', ip='147.197.129.5/24', mac='00:00:00:00:00:05')
    Host6 = self.addHost('h6', ip='147.197.129.6/24', mac='00:00:00:00:00:06')
    Host7 = self.addHost('h7', ip='147.197.129.7/24', mac='00:00:00:00:00:07')
    Host8 = self.addHost('h8', ip='147.197.129.8/24', mac='00:00:00:00:00:08')
        Host9 = self.addHost('h9', ip='147.197.129.9/24', mac='00:00:00:00:00:09')
        Host10 = self.addHost('h10', ip='147.197.129.10/24', mac='00:00:00:10:10:01')
        Host11 = self.addHost('h11', ip='147.197.129.11/24', mac='00:00:00:10:10:02')
        Host12 = self.addHost('h12', ip='147.197.129.12/24', mac='00:00:00:10:10:03')

        SERVER = self.addHost('SERVER', mac='00:00:00:10:10:04', ip='10.10.10.1/8')

    Switch1 = self.addSwitch('s1', cls=OVSSwitch)
    Switch2 = self.addSwitch('s2', cls=OVSSwitch)
    Switch3 = self.addSwitch('s3', cls=OVSSwitch)
    Switch4 = self.addSwitch('s4', cls=OVSSwitch)
    Switch5 = self.addSwitch('s5', cls=OVSSwitch)
    Switch6 = self.addSwitch('s6', cls=OVSSwitch)
    Switch7 = self.addSwitch('s7', cls=OVSSwitch)
    Switch8 = self.addSwitch('s8', cls=OVSSwitch)
        # Add links TODO 
    self.addLink(Host1, Switch5, cls=TCLink, bw=100)
    self.addLink(Host2, Switch5, cls=TCLink, bw=100)
    self.addLink(Host3, Switch5, cls=TCLink, bw=100)
    self.addLink(Host4, Switch6, cls=TCLink, bw=100)
    self.addLink(Host5, Switch6, cls=TCLink, bw=100)
    self.addLink(Host6, Switch6, cls=TCLink, bw=100)
    self.addLink(Host7, Switch7, cls=TCLink, bw=100)
    self.addLink(Host8, Switch7, cls=TCLink, bw=100)
    self.addLink(Host9, Switch7, cls=TCLink, bw=100)
    self.addLink(Host10, Switch8, cls=TCLink, bw=100)
    self.addLink(Host11, Switch8, cls=TCLink, bw=100)
    self.addLink(Host12, Switch8, cls=TCLink, bw=100)
    self.addLink(Switch1, Switch2, cls=TCLink, bw=500, delay='1ms', Loss='0.5%')
    self.addLink(Switch2, Switch4, cls=TCLink, bw=500, delay='1ms', Loss='0.5%')
    self.addLink(Switch4, Switch3, cls=TCLink, bw=500, delay='1ms', Loss='0.5%')
    self.addLink(Switch3, Switch1, cls=TCLink, bw=500, delay='1ms', Loss='0.5%')
    self.addLink(Switch1, Switch4, cls=TCLink, bw=500, delay='1ms', Loss='0.5%')
    self.addLink(Switch2, Switch3, cls=TCLink, bw=500, delay='1ms', Loss='0.5%')
    self.addLink(Switch3, Switch5, cls=TCLink, bw=500, delay='1ms', Loss='0.5%')
    self.addLink(Switch3, Switch6, cls=TCLink, bw=500, delay='1ms', Loss='0.5%')
    self.addLink(Switch4, Switch7, cls=TCLink, bw=500, delay='1ms', Loss='0.5%')
    self.addLink(Switch4, Switch8, cls=TCLink, bw=500, delay='1ms', Loss='0.5%')
    self.addLink(SERVER, Switch2, cls=TCLink, bw=1000)



topos = { 'mytopo': ( lambda: MyTopo() ) }
```

Comment: Try to put the Server and the hosts on the same subnet (10.0.0.0/8)

Comment: The code that you have provided clearly has an indentation error!